# Autofac resolution issues with merged assemblies

Tags: .net, autofac, ilmerge

We are using Autofac to compose our WPF application, and we use auto-registration for a number of the involved projects in this manner:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(type).AsSelf().AsImplementedInterfaces().PreserveExistingDefaults();
```

On top of that, we have explicit registrations for a number of types to have singleton lifestyle and also a number of `Func` factories. The registrations for the factories generally look like this:

```cs
   builder.Register<Func<ParameterType, ServiceType>>(
       c =>
       {
           var context = c.Resolve<IComponentContext>();

           return (parameter) => context.Resolve<ServiceImplementation>(
               new TypedParameter(typeof(ParameterType), parameter));
       });
```

All those registrations occur logically grouped within a number of modules that are registered in sequence.

All of this works fine until we start merging some of the involved assemblies. We need to do that because we have to obfuscate parts of the code, and all of the obfuscated assemblies must be merged to still be able to "find" each other's types. We also merge in the Autofac assemblies for that same reason.

In the merged application, resolving a simple instance registration works fine.

However, when the complex main ViewModel of the application is resolved, this exception occurs:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ScopeRestrictedRegistry' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Object scopeTag' of constructor 'Void .ctor(System.Object)'.
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
   at ApplicationModulesModule.<Load>b__1(IComponentContext c) in d:\Development\Production\Application\Application.Shell\AutofacSetup.cs:line 239
   at Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10`1.<Register>b__f(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Builder.RegistrationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass1`1.<ForDelegate>b__0(IComponentContext c, IEnumerable`1 p)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, Object& instance)
   at CaliburnBootstrapper.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) in d:\Development\Production\Application\Application.Shell\CaliburnBootstrapper.cs:line 102
   at Caliburn.Micro.BootstrapperBase.DisplayRootViewFor(Type viewModelType, IDictionary`2 settings)
   at CaliburnBootstrapper.<StartShell>b__13() in d:\Development\Production\Application\Application.Shell\CaliburnBootstrapper.cs:line 254
   at CaliburnBootstrapper.StartShell() in d:\Development\Production\Application\Application.Shell\CaliburnBootstrapper.cs:line 254
   at CaliburnBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass21.<GetConfiguredApplicationUpdater>b__18(Object o, FailArgs args) in d:\Development\Production\Application\Application.Shell\CaliburnBootstrapper.cs:line 340
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

`ApplicationModulesModule` is a `Module` that just registers all the other modules in its `Load` method.

From what I can make of the stack trace and the SmartAssembly (which we use for merging and obfuscation, although this already happens with unobfuscated builds) report is that the error apparently occurs rather deep within Autofac, and I can't follow what's going on.

I specifically can't make anything of that `scopeTag` thing; we're not using tagged scopes anywhere; the only Lifetime Scope that is explicitly created is the one that's used as the main container (`builder.Build().BeginLifetimeScope()`).

Does anyone have an idea what the issue might be here? If necessary/helpful, I can provide types/values for specific properties at given points in the stack trace.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the method/code from the `AutofacSetup.cs:line 239`? Because this is the place where the exceptions is comming so what you register/resolve there is causing the problem. By the way does your code works if you do not merge the assemblies?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that line (the stack trace was a bit overwhelming, so I didn't pick up all the information it provided); the problem wasn't really there, but it gave me an idea about where to continue searching. The real problem in the end turned out to be including Autofac in the merge - an Autofac container uses itself too, and blind auto-registration disrupts its inner workings. Both leaving Autofac out of the merge and a less naive approach at auto-registration can alleviate this.